# How to redirect to another page

Tags: django

Well, I have my own session and authentication routines in my app. When a user goes to `app/login/` page, if he or she is not loggen in, then he/she sees a form to submit, otherwise I want to redirect the user to the root page `app/`. login view looks like this:

```
def index(request):
    if sessionCheck(request):
        # here I want to redirect one level above to app/
        pass
    else:
        template = loader.get_template('login/login.html')
    ... other code which is not important
```

In `PHP`, I think, I would do it like this:

```
header("Location: /");
exit;
```

But how should I do exactly the same thing in `Django`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut function:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect('some-view-name')
```

You can also specify a URL apart from a named view. So if your index url does not have a name, you can specify '/'.

This shortcut function is essentially [the same as](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some-view-name'))
```

In order to have a named view, in your urls.py you have to provide a `name` argument. For instance:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^some-view$', views.something, name='some-view-name'),
]
```

More on that on [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view), [Django URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/).

Comment: Can you, please, advise me how should I set a named view? I never dealt with them.

Comment: Oh, I got it and made it work! Thank you, sir! In five minutes I will mark your answer as a solution.

Comment: I guess, in the context of the problem it should be `name='some-view-name'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

```
if sessionCheck(request):
    redirect(your_url)
else: 
    ...
```